# How to move an object to a location

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I'm unsure if this belongs here, or over at [Game Dev SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com), but will try here first.

Given a point mass $m$, with initial velocity $v_0$, and position $p_0$, I want to move this mass to, and stop at, position $p_d$. We are able to act on $m$ by applying a force with magnitude no greater then $f_{max}$ (so can undergo acceleration magnitude no larger then $a_{max} = \frac{f_{max}}{m}$).

There are many ways to do this. What I try to do, for any position $p$, and velocity $v$ is calculate the stopping distance, $s_{f_{max}}$ as
$$s_{f_{max}} = \frac{|v|^2}{2a_{max}}\tag{1}$$

Assuming the force is applied in the opposite direction as $v$. For simplicity, lets assume the angle between $v_0$ and $(p_d - p_0) = d$ is $0$. Then all I need to do is apply a force in the direction of $d$ until $(1)$ holds, then apply $f_{max}$ in direction opposite to $d$.

The situation when the angle between $v_0$ and $d$ just involves some way to get rid of the velocity orthogonal to $d$, and shouldn't be much harder.

Does this seem sensible?

Comment: The equation is valid, is that what you're asking? In the case of real life digital applications this won't work unless you use the $\leq$ sign though. It is unlikely that the position will be reached with infinite accuracy.

Comment: I'm asking because, when trying this, I'm getting a lot of overshoot. I couldn't find any bugs in what I've written - so wanted to make sure my strategy was at least valid.

Comment: It is, the problem lies elsewhere.